# AX2012 and UIPath

Tags: axapta, uipath, dynamics-ax-2012-r3, uipath-orchestrator

I'm working with UIPath to automate some processes in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012. When I use UIPath to indicate a button to press or a field to type into, UIPath gets a brainfreeze (stops working) and just chews on it for 3-6 minutes before it has completed. It works, but it take a ridicolous amount of time to make a process, as this is the case at every click. There is no problem when the process is running from orchestrator - it is only during development and only in AX. In all other programs it only takes a split second.

Does anyone know what causes AX to be this slow and how to fix it?

I have attached a video here, where you can see the issue: [Link to video showing performance issues](https://vimeo.com/393925871)

Thank you in advance

Comment: RPA's do not generally seem to work well with AX2012.

Comment: It does work when processes are running - no problem. It is only during development :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI Framework needed to be swithed. Pres F4 to go switch to AA before hovering over AX.

Answer (score 1):

This probably happens because the UiPath activity tries to load the whole table (including what is not directly visible) into memory. To workaround this, you might just filter your table in a way that you just have a few rows visible before you **Indicate on screen** the specific element.
Note that a similar behavior might occur during run time if there is a lot of data to capture.